# PowerQuery - How do I count events by dates spanning multiple years?

Tags: datetime, aggregate, powerquery

I would like to display activity counts by year e.g.

| Year | Created | Approved | Resolved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 10 | 5 | 19 |

the source records look like this:

| Record ID | Created Date | Approved Date | Resolved Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 9/17/2017 | 1/15/2018 | 11/1/2019 |

Using the example record the report for 2017 should look like:

| Year | Created | Approved | Resolved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I've linked the source table to a Calendar using the record Created Date. When I try to count any other status but Created, however, I get the count of records based on when they were created, and not when the event occurred:

| Year | Created | Approved | Resolved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

To count Date Resolved I've used: =calculate(count('source'[Resolved Date]),'calendar'[date]), which I know is incorrect. I want the count to be the number of items occurring during the year specified. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for BI solution, but in case anyone ever needs a  Powerquery/M solution

right click record_id and unpivot other columns

right click value column and tranform year...year

right click remove record_id column

add column, custom column, with formula =1

click attribute column and transform...pivot .. using the new custom column as value column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Record ID", Int64.Type}, {"Created Date", type date}, {"Approved Date", type date}, {"Resolved Date", type date}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Record ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Extracted Year" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", Date.Year, Int64.Type}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Year",{"Record ID"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each 1),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]